# How to use Picasso in onCreateView?

Tags: java, android, picasso

I have problem with Picasso code. In my fragment_home (*fragment of navigation bar*) is ImageView where I want to put image from "***image.com***" URL addres. 
Picasso code look like that

```
Picasso.get().load("image.com")
                .resize(300,200)
                .centerInside()
                .into(photo);
```

I cant write that into my HomeFragmentActivity where code suppose to be because findViewById isn't "working".

*HomeFragmentActivity* > Place where code have to be

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private ImageView photo;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home /*in this layout is ImageView where Picasso is inserting image from URL addres*/) , container, false);
    }
}
```

When code is somewhere else (*for example in MainActivity in onCreate method*) app will crash. Please help. Thanks.

**Write below you'r suggests, maybe Picasso code don't must be in HomeFragmentActivity ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare it like this :

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    photo = view.findViewById(R.id.photo);
    Picasso.with(context).load("url")
            .resize(300,200)
            .centerInside()
            .into(photo);
    return view;
}
```

or

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    photo = view.findViewById(R.id.photo);
    Picasso.with(context).load("url")
            .resize(300,200)
            .centerInside()
            .into(photo);
}
```

Comment: Better use onViewCreated